# Update EditorFor according to a Dropdown: Is there any way to use a JavaScript variable inside a HTML helper on MVC4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this dropdown list for a Model's property (Currency) in my View to which I have associated a JavaScript onchange function.

The goal of such function is to update some other field's (Rate) value according to a Dictionary property from the model (which maps Currencies to their Rate).

```
<td>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, new SelectList(ViewBag.CurrencyList, "Code", "Code"), new {onchange="update(this)"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Currency)
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function update(elem) {
           // alert("Currency changed!")
           document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(model => model.Rate)").value = '@Model.Currencies[<I_WISH_I_COULD_PUT_A_JS_VARIABLE_IN_HERE>]' 
        }
    </script>

</td>
```

I want that "I_WISH_I_COULD_PUT_A_JS_VARIABLE_IN_HERE" to be elem.value, but I get a syntax error as the JS variable is interpreted as a literal.
I can't seem to call an HTML helper with a Javascript value in it.

My goal is to update an EditorFor field according to the value selected in the combo box. but probably there's something wrong with my approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just read a similar question (sorry, I didnt see it before posting this one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500941/setting-razor-variables-in-javascript 

My approach didn't make sense as I was mixing server-side code with client-side.

For the record, I used ajax to retrieve the correct value and update the correspondent field. I can't post my code in the answer as I don't have enough rep, but my solution was similar to the one in the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, my approach didn't make sense at all as I was mixing server-side code with client-side.

I used ajax inside my function update(elem) to retrieve the correct value and update the correspondent field:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Currency?code=" + elem.value,
                success: function (msg) {
                    document.getElementById(RateId).value = msg;
                }
});
```

I hope this might help someone in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. HTML, CSS and JavaScript are output of your ASP.NET MVC web application project. JavaScript can't influence your web application the way you're trying above. There's no live connection between your MVC web application and JavaScript that somehow magically respond to one another.

To get this to work, I would place the values within `@Modal.Currencies` in some sort of JavaScript array. Then use that array to locate the value you need (with the JavaScript variable) to update the element with.

Comment: I ended up using an ajax call to retrieve the desired value and update the field. Thanks for your answer anyway =)